# How much would a race of 9' (2.75m) tall humanoids weigh?

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy

Trying to work up a race of creatures that resemble humans just taller, more muscular, and preferably, able to fit through doors. I just can't put my finger on how much they should weigh.

Comment: "More muscular"? How much so? Muscle effects BMI in a similar fashion to fat; here are some people who have a 27 BMI but are probably not countable as unhealthy and/or overweight: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-3234523/Is-Body-Mass-Index-waste-time-NHS-guidelines-say-BMI-27-overweight-don-t-look-it.html

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE BMI doesn't work for tall people. The BMI formula takes the square of the height ^2 even though as humans grow taller, they expand in all 3 dimensions according to the [square cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) - Why? Because using an exponent between 2 and 3 would make the math more difficult for an 18th century scholar instead of the more accurate ^2.5

Comment: 150 to 777 grams of pure muscle weight for each 1 centimetre of bone height for humans . 150 for underweight starved people and 777 for sumwrestlers, bodybuilders are close.

Comment: 8 foot = 243 centimetres, -3 for the skin and leave only the bone (the skin under your foot adds height).  multiply 240 centimetres by the level of muscularity you want (between 150 to 777) then add a surplus of 10% for the bone mass and add as much fat as you want.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Normal BMI doesn't; the adjusted BMI I cited below does.

Answer (score 11):

**ROBERT WADLOW, 8 ft 11.1 in**

You can easily use a real-life example as a reference point, [ROBERT WADLOW, is 8 ft 11.1 in](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/tallest-man-ever), almost equal to what you want and Robert's greatest recorded weight was **222.71 kg (35 st 1l b)** on his 21st birthday and he weighed 199 kg (31 st 5 lb) at the time of his death.

You can put up an approx estimate of around 230 - 250 KGs, for a healthy giant.

Comment: A horrible example. This is like saying "if we scaled people down then any medical problems that people with dwarfism have would occur". Robert Wadlow had Gigantism, which is an *problem* with your growth which causes bad proportions of the body. You cant compare a problematic growth to a healthy person's growth. You have to assume that the proportions and growth of the 9 foot person were healthy growth. Yes that does its not really full humanoid in shape as proportions have to adapt to the new size. Take Willks Grizzly bear as an example.

Comment: This answer, however, corresponds fairly well with the calculations made by KEY_ABRADE in his answer; 220kg there to 223kg here.  Not a bad approximation.

Answer (score 10):

Something more specific than L.Dutch's application of the square-cube law is the [new BMI formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#Proposed_new_BMI):

> ([HEIGHT METERS] ^ 2.5) * [BMI] / 1.3 = [WEIGHT KG]

For instance, let's say they have a BMI of 23 and a height of 9 feet:

> 30.48 centimeters to a foot
>
> 30.48 * 9 = 274.32 centimeters tall
>
> 274.32 / 100 = 2.7432 meters tall
>
> 2.7432 ^ 2.5 = 12.4636051005
>
> 12.4636051005 / 1.3 = 9.58738853885
>
> 9.58738853885 * 23 = 220.509936394 kilograms, or 486.1411941166471 pounds.

It works for normal humans as well as it does for 9-foot giants; let's take one with a BMI of 23 and a height of 5.75 feet:

> 30.48 centimeters to a foot
>
> 30.48 * 5.75 = 175.26 centimeters tall
>
> 175.26 / 100 = 1.7526 meters tall
>
> 1.7526 ^ 2.5 = 4.06637117725
>
> 12.4636051005 / 1.3 = 3.12797782865
>
> 3.12797782865 * 23 = 71.943490059 kilograms, or 158.608245678824 pounds.

That fits in pretty well on [this here BMI chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#/media/File:BMI_chart.png).

Comment: I think over there they say 5'9" rather than 5.75 feet

Comment: Probably a few too many sig figs there lol

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Heresy. Off to Decimal Detention with you.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Yes, daddy

Comment: Yes, not sure that such ballpark figures require microgram precision.

Comment: I like 5.75 feet. I am using that from now on (it is my height)

Answer (score 7):

**Taller and more muscular!**

Instead of these mathematic ideals and abstractions, let us consider a real life sometime-biped much like myself - robustly built.

[image: bear]

https://unofficialnetworks.com/2021/08/19/fat-bear-brooks-falls/

This muscular grizzly bear is probably a little over 8 feet and was estimated to weigh 1400 pounds which is a nice 100 stone. That is 2.44 meters and 635 kg for you moderns.

Comment: If that bear was a similarly proportioned human, doctors would call him OBESE. I doubt he could walk upright for very long with that much bulk.

Comment: How much does a grizzly bear weigh that's as tall as an average-sized human? Even at that size, I expect bears will still be a whole lot heavier. Their bodies are very different.

Comment: Well, I thought the other answers had done a reasonable job of scaling up humans.   I thought a bigger humanoid would reasonably be more robust (that is what we will call this bear, @SurpriseDog) and bears are extant semibipedal creatures to extrapolate from.

Comment: for one thing, the bear has much shorter legs and a longer torso than a human.

Comment: Bears also bulk up A LOT during the summer in order to survive winter hibernation, gaining as much as 70% of their spring weight.  Here's a link to some examples; https://www.doi.gov/blog/everything-you-want-know-about-katmai-national-parks-fat-bears-3  So a late spring bear might be the best comparison to a non-hibernating humanoid.

Comment: You can't use animals for comparison, structural differences will throw you off. Bears are built for storing lots of fat for hibernation as mentioned above, chimpanzees have a different muscle structure that quadruples their strength but reduces endurance, etc. etc. etc. All of these things affect weight-to-height ratio.

Answer (score 5):

Use the good old square cube law.

Weight is proportional to the volume of a body, thus the cube of the length.

If your creatures are X times the length of your reference sample, a good first approximation of their weight, all the rest being the same, is $X^3$.

To give you a numerical example, if they were 2 times as tall as a human, they would weigh $2^3=8$ times as much.

Comment: It would probably make sense to add that to compare a 9-foot-tall humanoid to a 6-foot-tall human, then one should multiply weight by 1.5^3 = 3.375. Depending on corpulence, a 9-foot-tall humanoid would probably weigh anywhere between 200 kg (quite slim) and... a mighty lot if they are truly obese.

Comment: This assumes proportionality though. If we compare various "pygmy" peoples (sorry for the potentially offensive term, I don't know a substitute) to the tallest human peoples, we tend to see that they aren't at all proportional. Likely for a 9ft humanoid, we will see some new proportions to help them remain mobile and avoiding premature heart failure.

Comment: @JohnO for preventing heart failure, see Giraffes. (which suggests that, yes, the heart could need to be proportionally bigger)

Comment: Square-cube only works over small size ranges.  Over large ranges, you get changes in proportion that invalidate simple square-cube scaling (compare, for example, an elephant's legs with those of a horse.)

Comment: *With a given waist line and height, how thick are their thighs?* So it's the Rocket Equation + the Square Cube law. Have fun with that.